# Get Operator Name In Flink Latency Metric

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to estimate end to end tuple latency of my events using the latency metrics exported by Flink (I am using a Prometheus metrics reporter). All is good and I can see the latency metric in my Grafana/Prom dashboard. Looks something like

```
flink_taskmanager_job_latency_source_id_source_subtask_index_operator_id_operator_subtask_index_latency{
  host="",instance="",job="",
  job_id="",job_name="",operator_id="",operator_subtask_index="0",
  quantile="0.99",source_id="",source_subtask_index="0",tm_id=""}
```

This test job I have is a simple `source->map->sink` operation, with parallelism set to 1. I can see from the Flink dashboard that all them gets chained together into one task. For one run of my job, I see two sets of latency metrics. Each set shows all quantiles like (.5, .95..). Only thing different between the two sets is the `operator_id`. I assumed this means one `operator_id` belongs to the `map` operator and the other belongs to the `sink`.

Now my problem is that is no intuitive way to distinguish between the two (find out which operator_id is the `map vs sink`), just by looking at the metrics. So my questions are essentially:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. What is the best way to distinguish the two operators? I tried assigning names to my `map` and `sink`. Even though these names show up in other metrics like `numRecordsIn`, the names does not show up in the latency metric.
3. Is there a way to get the mapping between `operator_id` and `operator_name`?

Comment: May I know how do you export task related metrics to Prometheus ? By default it seems it just export job manager related metrics to Prometheus . what else needed to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator_id` is currently a hash value either computed from the hash values of the inputs and the node itself or if you have set a UID via `uid` for an operator, it is computed as the `murmur3_128` hash of this id.

Please open a JIRA issue to add this feature to Flink.

Comment: Thanks. I added a Jira issue [FLINK-9653](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9653), but seems like there was one already [8592](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8592).